# How do you change the class of a TableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, controller, tableview

I have been trying to change the class of a TableViewController in the identity of it, but when I type in the name of the custom class that I want to change it to, it reverts back to `UITableViewController`

Here is what i'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Is the class you're trying to specify definitely a subclass of `UITableViewController`? And it's included in "Compile Sources" in the "Build Phases" of your Target's settings? We all change the class all the time, without incident, so I'm not sure what the issue could be (if it's not one of those simple things). If worst comes to worst, reboot your Mac (sometimes Xcode get's weird).

Comment: Thanks Rob! Rebooting worked. No clue why it did that! You might want to put that in an answer so I can mark it correct. And I do have to type the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the class you're trying to specify definitely a subclass of UITableViewController? And it's included in "Compile Sources" in the "Build Phases" of your Target's settings? We all change the class all the time, without incident, so this is curious.

If worst comes to worst, restart Xcode, and if that doesn't do it, reboot your Mac. Whenever you get unexplainable Xcode behavior, that's one of the steps we have to resort to nowadays. Sometimes Xcode get's weird. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

ALso give UITableViewController name in field of Storyboard ID & then check. Whatever you

change name of class every time also give same name in Storyboard ID field also.

Comment: That's not the issue. I never do that, and never have any problem.

Comment: But my case is also same and I am also then start to give same name of class in both field it work nicely then...

Comment: Are you saying that if you don't enter a storyboard ID that it forgets the class? I've never seen that behavior. The only time I put in a storyboard id is when I'm going to do `instantiateViewController` and need an identifier. Otherwise I leave it blank and everything works fine.

Comment: ya, but in my case it actually behave like as I am saying then I am start to give same name in both field but you are also right that when we need an identifier then we use Storyboard ID...